# self-study hints

Tags: self-learning, advice

A question to those who took rigirous courses like math 25 (Harvard), MATH 295-396 Michigan and etc
Being not able to collectively discuss problem sets from the course, as those who involved in official math programs do, is it a good idea to read enciclopedic-style books were practically all proofs are in explicit form (Zorich's/Shilov books for analysis, Kostrikin/Vinberg for algebra) write down ideas of proof then try to reconstruct proof from idea and finally check it?
Do lecturers give a hint of how to deal with homework?
There is another possibility, namely to try to reconstruct proof basing only on previous material without even looking at explicit solution, but it is very time-consuming and don't reproduce the way homework are done being discussed with classmates(some sort of brain-storming it seems). What do you think about it?

Comment: Personally I think your first idea is a potentially disastrous way to approach self-study in advanced rigorous mathematics, especially if it's in an area that's new to you. Without a professor to guide you to the most important ideas and make sure you don't spend undue amounts of time on the tangential ideas, it's a good idea to learn the material from texts written with the student in mind. Encyclopedic style expositions tend to be the most difficult sources to self study from because they cover everything and emphasize nothing.

Comment: In your opinion, how to compensate more efficiently lack of collective homework making? Thanks to internet there is no problem in obtaining assigments. The greatest problem is lack of team, in my country analysis course is more about memorising proofs night before exam and finding 200 tricky derivatives or integrals.
I suppose working in groups is some sort of brainstorming, but in practice, does not arise a situation where one gives the idea, even formalize and others thoroughly rewrite and then spend nights before midterm trying to do all steps of proof on their own.